# Login Screen/Background Change? (kubuntu)

Tags: kubuntu, login, lightdm

I have Kubuntu 13.04 (last version) and lightdm

I want to change my login screen background (not my wallpaper after I type my password. I'm talking for the image you see WHEN you type your password).
It shows a greyish "image" right now.
When I tried to use a picture from home and restarted the screen became white and it didn't show my image. I searched and found out that it because of some setings.

The problem is I'm very new to kubuntu and I don't want to mess things up with complicated setting from the terminal etc or to mess aroud with the root files because I won't be able to fix things.

Is there a simple solution as to how can I change this image? There is no option for me to download something there but only to load a picture.

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**At here**

KDE System Settings > Login Screen (LightDM); Theme tab

Background image

[image]

and the log in screen has new background.

**Why it is not working - White background - Check these**

**1) The image file has wrong extension**

Tested with jpg picture with the png extension.
The file properties is showing the right image format.

Right click the file > Properties: Information tab

[image]

The picture should have correct extension - If not the LightDM can't read the picture data.

**2) The image file has wrong permissions**

The user has forbidden the read of the image.

[image]

Right click the file > Properties: Permissions tab

The Owner/Group/Others should have the right to read the picture data.

Comment: It worked! :D
It was the image setting that was the problem. Thank you very much! It was extremely helpful :D

Now all I have to do is figure out how to change profiles with this format :P

Thank very very much :)

Answer (score 0):

In my situation I found another situation where it doesn't work (Why it is not working - White background). We have two possible causes above. Here is a third one.

I stored my wallpaper in the std user wallpaper folder of KDE (with Kubuntu 14.04):

`/home/[user_name]/.kde/share/wallpapers/`

It works for the backgrounds, but not for the login screen. I found out that even if jpg file permissions is allowed (RW/RW/R), `/home/[user_name]/.kde/share/wallpapers` is more restricted (RW/-/-). This is the reason why it doesn't work.

I just moved my jpg file to another location and it solved the issue.

Comment: You need to have the right premissions on the directories too. From top root directory `/` down through all to  `/h/[u]/.kde/s/wallpapers`.  So see to it that they have at least `x` rights, and possible `r` rights on `wallpapers`.
The directories above `wallpapers` only need `r` if you want to give the right to list the contents of that directory.  But as you know the names inbetween, you only need `x` to have access to it and lower directories/files.